# Reading kml file from saved email attachment

Tags: android-file

I have set up a file "import - export" process (using gmail client) in my app that would allow users to share kml files between each other or even just between devices. Please read the steps the user goes through to best understand.

File Out Process:
1) User adds placemarks to map.
2) User saves placemarks in kml format on /sdcard with user defined name (let's say "Saved.kml").
3) User "Exports" Saved.kml via gmail attachment.

File In Process:
1) User saves gmail attachment to Download folder on device.
2) User chooses "Import KML" and selects Saved.kml from list.
3) Everything works perfect! Placemarks appear on map just as exported/expected!

Except for one major flaw... This only works when you use the same device for your importing/exporting. I have two devices; Nexus 7 and LG Motion and it works great on either of them. But I can't get it to work between the two and I'm starting to get very frustrated.
Here is what I have tried:

Manifest changes:
 
android:sharedUserId="com.xxx.xxx"
android:sharedUserLabel="@string/sharedUserLabel"

Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "chmod 444 Saved.kml" ); // (need to support Android level 4)

Even tried this just before parsing Saved.kml -- importFileIn.renameTo(importFileOut);
and the file gets renamed but still fails to parse.

adb shell shows:
-rw-rw-r-- root     sdcard_rw      867 2013-02-28 10:39 Saved.kml
-rw-rw-r-- root     sdcard_rw      867 2013-02-28 11:44 SavedRenamed.kml

I used "adb push" and it showed the exact same userid/permissions on the pushed file and still won't load.

I was just at the point of last minute testing before publishing when I caught this.
Testing on the same device never had a single issue... Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Folks,
Asking this question through Stack Overflow made me type out everything that I've been pondering and finally led me to believe that this is not a file permission problem. By using Log.i I printed out the exception and found out this is actually a "File not found" error. Which of course is a whole different thing! Path error, problem solved!
Thanks for your patience with me.

Comment: To be more specific as to try to help:<br>

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific as to try to help:
 I was pulling data from files in the devices "Download" folder.
 On the Nexus 7 this is: "/storage/emulated/0/Download".
 On the LG Motion this is:"/sdcard/Download".
 By using "root.getAbsolutePath() + "/download" my problem was resolved.